# Where is my SSL certificate on Google Cloud hosting?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I've spent days trying to look through all of console.cloud.google.com to find details of the SSL Certificate we have for our website using Compute Engine, but there's absolutely nothing I can find.

I need support from Google, but I'm unable to get that.

I'm using Cloud Flare and their Full (Strict) SSL policy, which requires use of their universal SSL, and an origin SSL installed on the host. The origin SSL is due to be renewed at the end of Feb, so I need to update this quickly, but  I have no idea where to find details of it within Google.

There are a few references to SSL in the menu on the left hand side, but all of these show no results. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way your Compute Engine VM instance is configured to serve traffic.

If you are using a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates), you will have to associate the SSL certificates directly to it. You are looking into Self-managed SSL certificates, so [this documentation section](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#createresource) would be the one you need to follow.

Otherwise, if your instance serves the traffic directly, installing the SSL certificate depends on the server you are running. For example, for `NGINX` you would need to follow [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html), or for `Apache` you would need to use the [following](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I believe the very last link is the one that relates to me, but I don't understand any of the contents of that link at all. how can I just view the current certificate, and update it? Are you saying I need to do this entirely by SSH, or can I do it visually within Google Cloud somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you will have to SSH into the instance in order to update the certificate. I believe that [this documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217472077-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-certificate-in-Apache-httpd) is clearer with the steps that you will need to do.

Comment: This is just to do with CloudFlare though isn't it? Unless I haven't read it correctly, this isn't going to show me how to SSH into my google cloud shell to retrieve my private SSL details will it?

Comment: Yes, you will have to SSH into the machines, You can follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) to see which are the ways you can use to connect into the machine, depending on the OS it is running. Once you are connected to the machine, you can follow the previous guide to update the SSL certificate.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the delay. I still don't understand how to view the existing SSL certificate here, as i can SSH into the google cloud compute engine, and can find the .ssh directory, then inside the authorized_keys file there are 7 lines showing 'Added by Google' showing pairs of ssh-rsa and ecdsa-sha2-nistp256. Are these the public and private key I need to update, and if so, how do I know which one to update?

Comment: Type "ssl" on the search bar on the Google Cloud Console and a list of SSL certificates should appear.
Alternatively, go to **Network Services > Load balancing > advanced menu (beneath all load balancers) > Certificates**. There you will find listed all your SSL certificates, and you can also create a new one. If you click on a certificate you will see the details, and you can also check the REST equivalent by clicking on the link underneath the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Google-managed SSL certificates [1] are only supported for Load Balancers not for GCE instances, however you can point the traffic from the LB back to a GCE instance.

If you don't see any LB or SSL certificate in GCP portal it means your SSL is not being managed by Google at all, so check what service is running within your GCE instance to check the application configuration (like apache, nginx, etc..).

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs